# MapReduce internal error during partial document size

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea

I'm looking to get the document size from certain collection documents, they have a `validTo` field that I'm using for segregation. However, when trying to run the query below I get the also mentioned error. Any hints on this? It's strange as even removing the functions and using lambdas, I still get the same error quoting a an unexpected keyword "function".

I'm using IntelliJ's Query console.

Query:

```
db.runCommand({
mapReduce: "myCollection",
map: function(){
    emit(this._id, this)
},
reduce: function(key, values) {
    var ret = { count: 1, totalSizeBytes: bsonsize(values[0]), maxId: values[0]._id, minId: values[0]._id };
    var max = ret.totalSizeBytes;
    var min = ret.totalSizeBytes;
    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        var doc = values[i];
        var size = bsonsize(doc);
        ret.totalSizeBytes += size;
        ret.count++;
        if (size > max) { max = size; ret.maxId = doc._id }
        if (size < min) { min = size; ret.minId = doc._id }
    }
    return ret;
},
query: {"validTo": {$lt: new Date(2021,10,10)}},
out: { inline: 1 }
});
```

Error:

```
Command failed with error 139 (JSInterpreterFailure):
  'MapReduce internal error :: caused by ::
    SyntaxError: unexpected token: keyword 'function'' on server voucherservice-shard-00-01.5egqz.mongodb.net:27017.
  The full response is
    {
      "ok": 0.0,
      "errmsg": "MapReduce internal error :: caused by :: SyntaxError: unexpected token: keyword 'function'",
      "code": 139,
      "codeName": "JSInterpreterFailure",
      "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": {
          "$timestamp": {"t": 1671633783, "i": 438}
        },
        "signature": {
          "hash": {
            "$binary": {
              "base64": "Wj42UxI0paKLUqhhvx1WijmrUxA=",
              "subType": "00"
            }
          },
          "keyId": 7119429745099407365
        }
      },
      "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1671633783, "i": 438}}
    }
```

Comment: Since, `"_id"` is unique within a collection, won't `values.length` always be `1`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yeah it's very ugly but I think it will still work.

Comment: I'm curious about the _"IntelliJ's Query console"_.  Do you have a link that shows how to run MongoDB commands using it?  I've never used it and my limited Googling just showed some SQL queries, etc.

Comment: Why (deprecated) `mapReduce`? If `4.4+`, you can use `$bsonSize` in aggregation. A quick [playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oMx7-LUY-UG)

Comment: @rickhg12hs I couldn't find a link to it, it's quite strange, yet it has the same features as DataGrip: https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/mongodb/

Comment: @user20042973 good stuff! I wish I could tag your comment as as the answer, as while it doesn't take rid of the issue this is the right way to do things.